# Cohen-Macaulay local ring and its quotient by minimal prime ideal

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Assume $R$ is a Noetherian local ring which is Cohen-Macaulay, must there exist an ideal $I$ of $R$ such its radical is a minimal prime and the quotient ring $R/I$ is still Cohen-Macaulay? If the dimension of $R$ is less than 2, it is easy to see it is true.

Comment: I suspect this is false, but a counter-example would be non-trivial to construct. Is there a motivation for this question?